# Getting more information selecting by a Combobox Powershell

Tags: powershell, user-interface, powershell-3.0

Hello guys I'm currently coding an IHM in powershell to configure switches. I'm using a combobox to select a model. The combobx is generated using a dataview generated by a datasource, and the datasource is generated from a csv file by a foreach.

My problem is the following : I can only recover a single column.

Combobox:

```
$list1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox
$list1.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 9,45
$list1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(250,30)
$list1.DropDownStyle = "DropDownList"
$list1.BindingContext = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.BindingContext
$list1.DataSource = $vu1
$list1.ValueMember = "Model"
$list1.DisplayMember = "Model"  
$list1.SelectedValue = ""   
$mainfrm.controls.add($list1)
```

Reading infos

```
Write-Host "$list1.SelectedValue"
```

Edit foreach and creation of the dataview

foreach:

```
$ImportData = import-csv "E:\PS\A faire\equipement.csv" -Delimiter ';' | Select Model,Type,Port,Firmware,Comware
$table1 = New-Object system.Data.DataTable
$colonne1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Model,([string])
$table1.columns.add($colonne1)
$colonne2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Port,([string])
$table1.columns.add($colonne2)
$colonne3 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Comware,([string])
$table1.columns.add($colonne3)
$colonne4 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Firmware,([string])
$table1.columns.add($colonne4)
foreach ($data in $ImportData)
{
 $model = $data.Model
 $type = $data.Type
 $port = $data.Port
 $firmware = $data.Firmware
 $comware= $data.Comware
 $ligne1 = $table1.NewRow()
 $ligne1.Model = "$model "+"$type"
 $ligne1.Port = "$port"
 $ligne1.Comware = "$comware"
 $ligne1.Firmware = "$firmware"
 $table1.Rows.Add($ligne1)
}
```

Dataview

```
$vu1 = New-Object System.Data.DataView($table1)
```

Comment: What data type is `$vu1` (`$vu1.gettype()`)? and did you removed the header from the csv while importing?

Comment: It's a dataview $vu1 = New-Object System.Data.DataView($table1), and for the csv yes i removed the header using a foreach ($data in $data) {$colum1 = $data.exemple}

Comment: Did you really wrote ` ($data in $data)` in your code? You will overwrite your $data variable with the first entry of $data.

Comment: Please do not put code in comments because this makes it VERY unreadable. Edit your question and paste the *formatted* code in there.

Comment: Understood Theo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using 4 colums in the datasource I put everything in one and then a split.
Code after :

```
$ligne1.Model = "$model "+"$type " + "$port " + "$comware " + "$firmware "
```

Then you can use a split() to have a usable value.